# Why is this address changing in gdb?

Tags: c++, unix, gdb

I'm debugging a very simple assembly program (SPARC) with gdb and am experiencing a strange issue. I'm trying to use gdb to print the arguments in argv to the main function of my program. For some reason, the address in $i1, the second argument to main, is sometimes changed to point to -1. Here's a copy-paste of my gdb session:

```
(gdb) p/x $i1
$1 = 0xffbff084
(gdb) x/x 0xffbff084
0xffbff084:     0xffbff1e4
(gdb) x/s 0xffbff1e4
0xffbff1e4:     "..."
(gdb) x/x 0xffbff088
0xffbff088:     0xff
(gdb) x/x 0xffbff084
0xffbff084:     0xff
```

I used "..." instead of the actual path that was printed.

I printed the first argument correctly, but instead of getting the address of the second argument, gdb says the next value is -1. I went back to check the address of the first string again and gdb says it's -1 too even though I had just found it to be something else!

This isn't a multi-threaded program, so I don't know what could be changing the address :/

edit: Only appears to happen AFTER using x/s to print the contents at the address.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gdb 'x' command accepts the the print format and size as options after the slash. In the [manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html#Memory) it says:

> Each time you specify a unit size with x, that size becomes the default unit the next time you use x.

It also says:

> For the ‘s’ format, the unit size defaults to ‘b’, unless it is explicitly given.

So what is happening is that after you give the command `x/s`, subsequent `x` commands are interpreted as being for byte length. Thus it is printing only the first byte of the memory you are trying to inspect, which happens to be 0xff.

Try printing the addresses with `x/xw` instead of just `x/x`.